# Count all amount of numbers in 2d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, go

I'm trying to write console minesweeper, but cant figure out how to iterate over 2d array, and count amount of "-1" around each of element. My array looks like

```
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 -1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 -1 -1]
[0 0 0 -1 -1]
```

Where "-1" that is mine. I've tried to simply iterate over it with code

```
for i := 0; i < row; i++ {
numb := 0
    for j := 0; j < col; j++ {
         if ary[i-1][j-1] == -1 {
             numb ++ } 
         }
         if ary[i-1][j] == 1 {
             numb ++ }
         //rest of code omitted

    }
```

But that resulted in huge amout of code, which is hard to read and understand. Is there more flexible way, to check all elements around `current` in `for-iterator`, so in result it would look like

```
[0 1  1   1 0]
[0 1 -1   1 0]
[0 1  2   2 1]
[0 0  1  -1 -1]
[0 0  1  -1 -1]
```

Comment: you have an array of array correct ? why cant you have 2 foor loops?

Comment: @Ruben check each its element

Comment: If you're doing a minesweeper, you should probably keep track of the number of mines instead of calculating it everytime.

Comment: @Avdept you can use the trick with min max shown in my answer and it makes use of the special value -1. I think in your last picture the 3rd line needs to be `[0 1 2 3 2]` and the following lines `[0 0 2 -1 -1]`

Comment: @sturcotte06 i have number of mines in one of variables. however i don't track its coordinates

Comment: Use objects instead of integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i := 0; i < row; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < col; j++ {
        if ary[i][j] == -1 {
            for k := max(0, i - 1); k <= min(row - 1, i + 1); k++ {
                for l := max(0, j - 1); l <= min(col - 1, j + 1); l++ {
                    if ary[k][l] != -1 {
                        ary[k][l] ++
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The first two outer loops go through the array. If the observed number is `-1` then it increases all surrounding cells unless there is a mine on that field. To avoid the checks if `ary[k][l]` is not outside of bounds the bounds are calculated before by using the trick with min / max to ensure that `k` and `l` are not outside of bounds. E.g. `max(0, i-1)` will always return `i-1` unless `i-1` is smaller than `0`, then it returns `0`.

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for. But could you in 2 words describe your logic?

Comment: @Avdept I tried to put it in words now, it was surprisingly difficult compared to the algorithm itself.